# How to wrap a row of buttons in visually appealing way

Tags: gui-design

[image]

wraps to this on narrow screens:

[image]

What comes to my mind is wrapping like this:
2x
2x
1x (and the 1x placed in the middle of the third row)

Any ideas?

Comment: you could simply use media queries and make the font or padding smaller. But Alvaro's answer is a way better approach, for any screen (you can use vertical separators on wide screens)

Comment: Yes, this is probably the best solution -> mq.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Group related buttons together
- Leave some space between rows so the group relation is understood

[image]

(Although without context, in my opinion the phrasing doesn't look very clear and the amount of buttons seems a bit overwhelming).

Comment: Context: Buttons are below a graph which control the graph data displayed in the canvas. But does this look appealing? Yes I can use mq, but the question is rather how to adapt it to look nice. This does not look nice to me. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If you could upload the whole screen maybe it'll be easier to suggest a better solution.